# Authentication OAuth2 to API REST using cURL

Tags: shell, rest, curl, oauth-2.0

i'm having a little problem here. I've been trying to authenticate (protocol OAuth2) to a REST API using the cURL command. I use the following command line :

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=login_id&client_secret=password&grant_type=client_credentials" http://localhost:9001/rest/oauth/token
```

But it doesn't work and the command returns :

```
{"status":"error","message":"Parameter is required for method Load."}
```

But I don't know parameter they are talking about. Do you have any idea where the problem could come from ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: Here is a solution: https://labs.cx.sap.com/2012/06/18/trying-out-oauth2-via-curl/